# How to handle special cases in make?

Tags: linux, perl, makefile, gnu-make

I have following makefile where a bunch of `pla` files are processed to `a` files

`$(SRC_DIR)` has `dec.pla`,`inc.pla`, and many more `*.pla` files

`$(FILES)` = all corresponding `*.a` files and instead of `dec.a` I have `dec0.a` and `dec1.a`  since I want to generate two different files `dec0.a` and `dec1.a` corresponding to `dec.pla` based on the variable that is being passed. How do I accomplish this?

```
$(FILES):$(TMP_DIR)/%.a      : $(SRC_DIR)/%.pla                
        $(BASE_CMD)        < $< > $@

$(FILES):$(TMP_DIR)/dec0.a   : $(SRC_DIR)/dec.pla
        $(BASE_CMD) -D c=0 < $< > $(TMP_DIR)/dec0.a

$(FILES):$(TMP_DIR)/dec1.a   : $(SRC_DIR)/dec.pla
        $(BASE_CMD) -D c=1 < $< > $(TMP_DIR)/dec1.a
```

I tried the above and got the error

```
proc.make:8: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(FILES): $(TMP_DIR)/dec0.a: $(SRC_DIR)/dec.pla` is a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern)... without pattern. This is not valid make syntax.

You could try:

```
FILES1 := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.pla,$(TMP_DIR)/%.a,$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.pla))
FILES2 := $(TMP_DIR)/dec0.a $(TMP_DIR)/dec1.a

$(FILES1): $(TMP_DIR)/%.a: $(SRC_DIR)/%.pla                
        $(BASE_CMD) < $< > $@

$(FILES2): $(TMP_DIR)/dec%.a: $(SRC_DIR)/dec.pla
        $(BASE_CMD) -D c=$* < $< > $@
```